# How to Update post status using meta data in Custom post TYpe

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have custom post type and have some some meta field it. I have a select field 'Publish' to change post status. if I set it 'yes' and click on Update button then post will be published and if i set it to 'no' then post should be save as 'Draft'. you can see screenshot of my custom post type-

[image]

What code should I used to in `add_action( 'save_post','save_my_data')`. or any other idea.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to use your own select form to update a post's published status instead of the publish/unpublish buttons?  Something like this would work for that:

```
function save_my_data($post_id){
    if($_POST['publish'] == 'yes' && get_post_status($post_id) != 'publish'){ //whatever your post variable is
        remove_action('save_post', 'save_my_data'); //if you don't unhook the function you'll have an infinite loop
        wp_publish_post($post_id);
        add_action('save_post', 'save_my_data'); //rehook the function       
    }
    if($_POST['publish']) == 'no' && get_post_status($post_id) == 'publish'){
        remove_action('save_post', 'save_my_data'); //if you don't unhook the function you'll have an infinite loop
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ));
        add_action('save_post', 'save_my_data'); //rehook the function
    }
}
```

You would probably want to add some error handling and optimize it a little bit.  You also might want to account for the other post statuses outlined here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Default_Statuses

Comment: Simple but perfect, I had been trying for hours to find a solution but without success.