# Change post status by custom fields

Tags: custom-field, post-status

I'd like to update my post status (of my own CPT) based on custom field "played". If played is 1 i want that the post shall be published, but if the custom field played is 0 the post shall be draft also if I tried to publish it.

Is it possible?

I tried to search in the forum but nothing found that works... also tried the code here but not working...

[How to Update post status using meta data in Custom post TYpe](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180253/how-to-update-post-status-using-meta-data-in-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to use [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook. Here's how:

```
function change_post_status_based_on_custom_field( $post_id ) {
    // If this is just a revision, don't do anything.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    // Get field value
    $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'played', true );

    $status = $value ? 'publish' : 'draft';

    // If status should be different, change it
    if ( get_post_status( $post_id ) != $status ) {
        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_status_based_on_custom_field' );

        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => $status
        ) );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_status_based_on_custom_field' );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_status_based_on_custom_field' );
```

Answer (score 1):

That might be quite a bit of code to paste in here, but your strategy should be along the lines of:

- Hook onto post_save event:

  - make a static variable that you've already checked this, to prevent infinite recursion in the case that you update the post from within this function.
  - check if custom field == 'played'

    - if it is, modify the post status as needed, and do wp_update_post.